# What values are returned from model.evaluate() in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I've got multiple outputs from my model from multiple Dense layers. My model has `'accuracy'` as the only metric in compilation. I'd like to know the loss and accuracy for each output. This is some part of my code.

```
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, [y_test_one, y_test_two], verbose=1)
```

When I printed out the scores, this is the result.

```
[0.7185557290413819, 0.3189622712272771, 0.39959345855771927, 0.8470299135229717, 0.8016634374641469]
```

What are these numbers represent?

I'm new to Keras and this might be a trivial question. However, I have read the docs from Keras but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Quoted from [`evaluate()` method documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#evaluate-method):

> **Returns**
>
> Scalar test loss (if the model has a single output and no metrics) or
> list of scalars (if the model has multiple outputs and/or metrics).
> The attribute `model.metrics_names` will give you the display labels
> for the scalar outputs.

Therefore, you can use `metrics_names` property of your model to find out what each of those values corresponds to. For example:

```
from keras import layers
from keras import models
import numpy as np

input_data = layers.Input(shape=(100,)) 
out_1 = layers.Dense(1)(input_data)
out_2 = layers.Dense(1)(input_data)

model = models.Model(input_data, [out_1, out_2])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

print(model.metrics_names)
```

outputs the following:

```
['loss', 'dense_1_loss', 'dense_2_loss', 'dense_1_mean_absolute_error', 'dense_2_mean_absolute_error']
```

which indicates what each of those numbers you see in the output of `evaluate` method corresponds to.

Further, if you have many layers then those `dense_1` and `dense_2` names might be a bit ambiguous. To resolve this ambiguity, you can assign names to your layers using `name` argument of layers (not necessarily on all of them but only on the input and output layers):

```
# ...
out_1 = layers.Dense(1, name='output_1')(input_data)
out_2 = layers.Dense(1, name='output_2')(input_data)
# ...

print(model.metrics_names)
```

which outputs a more clear description:

```
['loss', 'output_1_loss', 'output_2_loss', 'output_1_mean_absolute_error', 'output_2_mean_absolute_error']
```

Comment: I have retuned recall, precision, AUC and accuracy which is fine, but how can we access each metric separately so that we can use them wherever we want? I have tried subscripting and dot syntax to access the properties or indices.

Comment: It's also possible to add  return_dict=True to evaluate method and you will get the name of the metrics!

Answer (score 1):

We should be clear that the "loss" figure is the sum of **ALL** the losses calculated for each item in the x_test array. x_test would contain your test data and y_test would contain your labels. The loss figure is the sum of ALL the losses, not just one loss from one item in the x_test array.