# Using sample_weights with fit_generator()

Tags: machine-learning, keras, time-series, generator, autoregressive-models

Inside an autoregressive continuous problem, when the zeros take too much place, it is possible to treat the situation as a zero-inflated problem (i.e. ZIB). In other words, instead of working to fit `f(x)`, we want to fit `g(x)*f(x)` where `f(x)` is the function we want to approximate, i.e. `y`, and `g(x)` is a function which output a value between 0 and 1 depending if a value is zero or non-zero.

Currently, I have two models. One model which gives me `g(x)` and another model which fits `g(x)*f(x)`.

The first model gives me a set of weights. This is where I need your help. I can use the `sample_weights` arguments with `model.fit()`. As I work with tremendous amount of data, then I need to work with `model.fit_generator()`. However, `fit_generator()` does not have the argument `sample_weights`.

Is there a work around to work with `sample_weights` inside `fit_generator()`? Otherwise, how can I fit `g(x)*f(x)` knowing that I have already a trained model for `g(x)`?

Comment: Have you tried index slicing? I.e. if you have 23000 prices you can simply slice each 5th one of these using `data[0:23000:5, :, :]`. The returned array will have shape `(4600, 45, 41)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can provide sample weights as the third element of the tuple returned by the generator. From Keras documentation on [`fit_generator`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator):

> **generator:** A generator or an instance of `Sequence` (`keras.utils.Sequence`) object in order to avoid duplicate data when using multiprocessing. The output of the generator must be either
>
> - a tuple `(inputs, targets)`
> - a tuple `(inputs, targets, sample_weights)`.

**Update:** Here is a rough sketch of a generator that returns the input samples and targets as well as the sample weights obtained from model `g(x)`:

```py
def gen(args):
    while True:
        for i in range(num_batches):
            # get the i-th batch data
            inputs = ...
            targets = ...
            
            # get the sample weights
            weights = g.predict(inputs)
            
            yield inputs, targets, weights
            
            
model.fit_generator(gen(args), steps_per_epoch=num_batches, ...)
```

Comment: Can you build a little snippet to show me how it works?

Comment: @user1050421 Do you want to know how to define a data generator for a Keras model or how to return sample weights in a generator?

Comment: @user1050421 You can find an example of `Sequence` based generator [here](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence).

Comment: Are you up to explain both?

Comment: @user1050421 Sure, I added an update. Please take a look. [This tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) might also help (It is using `Sequence` based generators, not Python generators).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! If you can upvote my question, I will give you this bounty

Comment: @today what about with evaluate_generator? I can't seem to get the same logic you use here to work.

Comment: @StatsSorceress I have not tried that, but according to the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#evaluate_generator) it must be the same, i.e. you can return the sample weights as the third element of the tuple from the generator.

Comment: @today Aha! The third - not the fourth? I'm sorry, I read the docs that you linked but I still don't understand because the docs say that it outputs a list of scalars, but doesn't say what each value at each position must represent....I think I'm making this too hard?

Comment: @StatsSorceress That's a different question. They are loss value and the metric values returned for each output (if the model has multiple outputs). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51303340/2099607) might help you to understand it better.

Comment: I have a similar problem where I need the sample_weights from the generator in my custom loss function...this post helped me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999225/how-to-access-sample-weights-in-a-keras-custom-loss-function-supplied-by-a-gener