# Keras returns binary results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification

I want to predict the kind of 2 diseases but I get results as binary (like 1.0 and 0.0). How can I get accuracy of these (like 0.7213)?

---

Training code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

# Intialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
import h5py

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)


training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')


classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 100,
                         epochs = 1,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 100)
```

---

Single prediction code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img,image

test_image = image.load_img('path_to_image', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)

print(result[0][0]) # Prints 1.0 or 0.0
# I want accuracy rate for this prediction like 0.7213
```

---

The file structures is like:

- test_set

  - benigne

    - benigne_images
  - melignant

    - melignant_images
- training set

Training set structure is also the same as test set.

Comment: You can use `evaluate` method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51303340/2099607).

Comment: evaluate function requires x_train and y_train parameters, but how can get y_trains? I mean, this code generates it by itself using directory names.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can use `evaluate_generator()` method if you have defined a generator for test data.

Comment: Where should I use it? One line above of predict() method? I've read the documentation but cannot understand how to use it. By the way, I'm trying to predict only one image, not whole test images.

Comment: Do you want to predict on `test_set` generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** As you clarified in the comments, you are looking for the probabilities of each class given one single test sample. Therefore you can use `predict` method. However, note that you must first preprocess the image the same way you have done in the training phase:

```
test_image /= 255.0
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
```

The `result` would be the probability of the given image belonging to class one (i.e. positive class).

---

If you have a generator for test data, then you can use [`evaluate_generator()`](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#evaluate_generator) to get the loss as well as the accuracy (or any other metric you have set) of the model on the test data.

For example, right after fitting the model, i.e. using `fit_generator`, you can use `evaluate_generator` on your test data generator, i.e. `test_set`:

```
loss, acc = evaluate_generator(test_set)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I don't need loss and acc of model. I will give a single image to trained NN and I expect the output of this image as (acc: 0.7324 for this image, not model).

Comment: @A.Görünücü The accuracy for a single prediction is either 100% or 0%. Further, you need to have the true label for that sample to be able to compare it with the predicted label to find the accuracy of prediction.

Comment: In this project, I'm trying to determine diseases. So, I download some images and used them to train. The main purpose is that when I get a new disease photo, I want from model to say "0.24 Disease A, 0.76 Disease B". There are only two diseases in my case. Isn't is possible to get this kind of prediction from using one image as input? For example, the result of `predict()` method.

Comment: @A.Görünücü So you want the probabilities and not accuracy. Actually, in this case the output of `model.predict()` is the probability of the class one (i.e. positive class) for the given sample. The probability of the class zero (i.e. negative class) would be 1 minus that number.

Comment: @A.Görünücü And also don't forget that you need to do the same preprocessing you have done on the images when training the model. So you need to rescale the test image by dividing it by 255.0. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: 0.0 Disease A, 1.0 Disease B is also a valid probability, don't forget this.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes, but it is very unlikely that this model gives such a sharp prediction **given a properly preprocessed image.**