# Whats the output for Keras categorical_accuracy metrics?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, keras-metrics

I cant find proper description of metrics outputs.

For example if I use

`model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])`

then I get loss and accuracy `tr_loss, tr_acc = model.train_on_batch(X, Y)`

if I compile with `metrics=['categorical_accuracy']` then I get 2 numbers as well,

but what are they ?

EDIT: I did this: `print(model.metrics_names)` and got: `['loss', 'categorical_accuracy']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What values are returned from model.evaluate() in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51299836/what-values-are-returned-from-model-evaluate-in-keras)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `accuracy` metric is actually a placeholder and keras chooses the appropriate accuracy metric for you, between `binary_accuracy` if you use `binary_crossentropy` loss, and `categorical_accuracy` if you use `categorical_crossentropy` loss.

So in this specific case, both metrics (`accuracy` and `categorical_accuracy`) are literally the same, and `model.evaluate` return loss and accuracy.

Comment: binary and category aren't the same at all. I have 8 categories and binary is only for 2.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please post the two numbers you mentioned?
I guess they are `loss` (`categorical_crossentropy` in your case) and metrics you added. (`accuracy` or `categorical_accuracy` as configured in your case).