# Adding f1_score metric in compile method for Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network

In Keras, assuming I have `compile` as:

```
model.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And, for some reason, I want to use `model.evaluate()` instead of `model.predict()`, how can add `f1 score` metric to the argument `metrics=['accuracy']`?

Thank you,

Comment: No straightforward way. Compute precision and recall separately (`metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()]`), and then compute f1-score directly from precision and recall

Comment: Is `evaluate` output array in order? I mean the first value is loss, followed by accuracy, followed by precision, ... ?

Comment: You can see the order of metrics in `model.metrics_names` property. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51303340/5154274) answer